# create dictonary with array as value in key value pair : java Script

Tags: javascript

Am trying to achieve something like the following :

```
  Key                      value

fruit               apple,orange,banana,grapes
cooldrinks          pepsi,cococola,miranda
snaks               lays,kurkure
```

for that i use the code as:

```
<script>
var vars = [{key:"key", value:"val1",value:"val2",value:"val3",value:"val4"}];
vars[0].key = "fruit";
vars[0].val1 = "apple";
vars[0].val2 = "orange";
vars[0].val3 = "banana";
vars[0].val4 = "grapes";
</script>
```

But it is not possible for large dictionaries how can i implement such dictionaries with huge content? can anyone suggest me a simplest method?

In the case of dynamic array what should i need to change in my code?

Comment: I guess what you really want is `var data = {fruit: ['apple', 'orange', ...], snaks: ['lays', 'kurkure'], ..}`. I recommend to learn about objects by reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first of all create this key/values object:

```
function Pairs() {
    this.key= "",
    this.values= new Array()
}
```

this object will hold your key and values for all the things.

Next up you need to create a dictionary array to hold all the Pairs:

```
var dictionary = new Array();
```

then, create your objects, fill them up with data and add them to dictionary:

```
var fruit = new Pairs();
fruit.key = "fruit";
fruit.values[0] = "banana";
fruit.values[1] = "Orange";
fruit.values[2] = "Apple";
dictionary.push(fruit);  //adding fruit to dictionary

var car = new Pairs();
car.key = "car";
car.values[0] = "Honda";
car.values[1] = "Toyota";
car.values[2] = "Ferrari";
dictionary.push(car);   //adding car to dicitonary
```

once dictionary is populated, you can access the objects like:

```
dictionary.length; //get the length of all the objects present in dictionary
dictionary[0].key; //get the key of a particular object
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/LLpoeaqr/)**

Comment: For me, this is an horrible answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var data = [
  {fruit: ['apple','orange','banana','grapes']},
  {cooldrinks: ['pepsi','cocacola','miranda']},
  {snacks: ['lays','kurkure']}
]
```

Comment: Would add another +1 for the fixed spelling of snacks but can't.

Comment: what are the changes i need to made in the code in the case of dynamic dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Why you use an array for this? Use an *object* instead:

```
var dictionary = {
   key1: ["value1", "value2"],
   key2: ["value3", "value4"]
};
```

If you want to obtain all keys, you may use `Object.keys`:

```
var allKeys = Object.keys(dictionary);
```

Also, you can access a key using *dot syntax* or *indexed syntax*:

```
var key1value = dictionary.key1;
key1value = dictionary["key1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use js objects to do this

```
var dictionary = [
  { fruit: ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'grapes'] },
  { cooldrinks: ['pepsi', 'cocacola', 'miranda'] },
  { snacks: ['lays', 'kurkure'] }
];
```

You can then access them like this

```
dictionary.fruit;     // returns apple, orange, banana, grapes
dictionary.snacks[0]; // returns lays
```

You can even use `[]` notation

```
dictionary["fruit"][0];// returns apple
```